# Storyboard reference on iOS below 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I am playing with new Storyboard references. According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html) minimum requirement for iOS is version 9.0.

However, I have successfully deployed test app with simple show segue between two storyboards inside same app connected with Storyboard reference to iOS 8.3 device and Simulator with iOS 8.0.

Is documentation wrong, or I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's backwards compatible to 8.0 with the exception of relationship segues. See [the release notes for Xcode 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html)

```
Storyboard References may now be deployed to iOS 8, OS X 10.10, and watchOS 1.
Backwards-deployed Storyboard References may not be connected to relationship segues and may not refer to storyboards in external bundles. (21275172)
```