# Xcode storyboards unresponsive after adding language localizations

Tags: ios, xcode, optimization, localization, uistoryboard

I've recently added many language localizations (localizable strings) to an Xcode (7.3.1) project.

Since around that time, working with the storyboards in Xcode has been incredibly difficult, and Xcode at times has been very unresponsive. Typically when working with storyboards the mouse turns into a colorful spinning pinwheel for about 5 seconds, then I get a few seconds where I can work, until the spinning pinwheel shows up for another 5 seconds again.

When editing swift code, where code is the only window onscreen, this issue doesn't seem to occur, the issue only seems to occur when editing the storyboard and only ever since it seems after adding localizations.

In fresh new projects, projects with no localizations, there are no such issues, project storyboards can easily be edited with no long interrupting pauses.

I've tried deleting the Derived Data folder and that didn't improve things. I'm considering removing all localizations and putting them back in at the end of the project, but this doesn't seem efficient to do either.

1 - Is there a way to disable localizations without deleting them in the project?

2 - Is there a way to remove localizations and then drop them back into the project at a later date efficiently? (When I say efficiently I mean easily such as drag and drop as opposed to adding them back in via multiple menus and dialogue boxes.)

3 - Any suggestions as to what might be going on here with this unique Xcode behavior?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

2 -
delete the files `by reference`, and add them later (`File`>`Add Files`)

3 - When storyboards contains so many things, it will take time to load. Its good practice to use multiple storyboards which contains specific modules. So it will be readable and will load faster.

This might also help: 
If you use ios8 and above you can use [storyboard references](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226)

just watch out for [ios8 limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691302/storyboard-reference-on-ios-below-9-0)

To improve loading or reduce loading frequently, select your storyboard, press `Edit`, and deselect `Automatically Refresh Views`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Ted This is a project for iOS7>, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Unfortunately Xcode wouldn't allow multiple selections of localizations so deletions had to be one at a time. For anyone reading, the issue appears to have proved itself to be too many (unknown quantity) localizations causing the slow down, so I progressively removed some localizations temporarily so that it was possible to work on the storyboard uninterrupted. The more localisations I removed, the better the responsiveness of the storyboard became. Cheers

Comment: In my opinion, use 1 storyboard or IB for left to right, and 1 storyboard or IB for right to left. No need for all the languages :)